# Generating a list of random numbers based on probabilities in numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy, random, probability

You have a list of n elements. Each element in list is either [0,1,2,3]. There is a 58% chance any given element in the list is a 1, and a 42% (1 - 0.58) chance any given element is [0,2,3].

Using python/numpy, how may I go about generating multiple lists as such?

Bonus: Generalized such that you can easily change the set of numbers in the list (i.e., [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] instead of [0,1,2,3]).

Thanks

Comment: `np.random.choice` has an optional `p` parameter where you can put the probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 4), p=[0.14, 0.58, 0.14, 0.14])
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic version, allowing the range to be set through `y`:

```
import numpy as np

y=4

np.random.choice(np.arange(0, y), p=[0.58 if x==1 else (1-0.58)/(y-1) for x in range(0,y)])
```